# submit Select_tag values from form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am puzzled with `params` from a form view using select_tag. 
The form content is something like:

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :begin %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :begin %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end %><br>
    <!-- %= f.datetime_select :end % -->
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :plan%><br>
    <%= select_tag("plan", options_for_select([['3个月', 1], ['6个月', 2],  ['12个月', 3]], 3)) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :activiated %><br>
    <div id=activiationid>This will be changed after you have made payment </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :bill %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :bill %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
    <%= button_tag t('Cancel'), type: "submit", name: "cancel", value: true %> 
  </div> 
  <div class="actions">
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The corresponding action method

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
 def update
    respond_to do |format|
      byebug
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
    def order_params
      byebug
      params.require(:order).permit(:begin, :end, :plan, :activiated, :bill)
    end
end
```

Once the form is submit, the `params` in `order_params` is

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"b6D7xOlS0vf+e0WkdrBA07fQxOrahsrmEMtIws2N2hfBsyHTq+qPvQJ0CeSKNW3DQk3KALWknlcFApYdtPJ9BA==", "order"=>{"begin(1i)"=>"2017", "begin(2i)"=>"1", "begin(3i)"=>"5", "begin(4i)"=>"18", "begin(5i)"=>"58", "bill"=>"3420"}, "plan"=>"1", "commit"=>"Update Order", "controller"=>"orders", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"2841"}
```

The questions are:

1. why the *plan* field, which is select_box, is out of *order* sections in the `params`.
2. How can I built the @order, *plan* of which is initialized.
   3． How to better write `<%= select_tag("plan", options_for_select([['3个月', 1], ['6个月',` so that the *plan* will be inside of `params`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've bumped into a reserved-word problem.

In your order_params definition there are 2 attributes, :begin and :end, that must be changed (their name).

```
begin
```

and

```
end
```

are reserved words in ruby - you can see a list here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Language-Basics/Rubysreservedwords.htm

Keep in mind that rails has it's own set of reserved words which you can google.  What is happening is that rails is seeing `end` and misinterpreting the situation and ending the params hash. Try changing their names to start_time and end_time or something similar.

---

#### Update

For using select_tag you have to make sure that you set a `name` param.  Otherwise it will not be included in the array/object that is the rest of the form data.  You can see an example of this if you use your 'inspect' feature of your browser.  Look at any field name, you'll see it looks something like:

```
name="order[attributename]"
```

You can set this name manually after options_for_select, OR you could use the form_for standard select instead, in which the input is attached to the form object:

```
<%= f.select(:plan, [['3个月', 1], ['6个月', 2], ['12个月', 3]], {selected: 3} )%>
```

Comment: I changed the table field names "begin' and "end", and it is not this reason. ``params.require(:order)`` does not contain `plan` info, so the constructed order misses `plan`. I do not understand the `plan` is not in the `:order` field.

Comment: Thanks. `f.select` fixes all